# Вывод результата output

Tags: javascript, строки, input

Есть 4 поля и кнопка button как вывод результата. Есть функция, которая высчитывает результат ввода каждого из поля. Как организовать output для вывода результата:

```
function Go() {
    var x1 = parseInt(document.forml.acht_mes.value);
    var x2 = parseInt(document.forml.kol_mes.value);
    var x3 = parseInt(document.forml.acht_den.value);
    var x4 = parseInt(document.forml.kol_den.value);
    var result=((x1*x2)+(x3*x4))/(x2+x4);
 }
```

Событие onClick должно вывести результат функции в пятое поле, как output:

```
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Введите первое число" required="required" class="input-txt" name="acht_mes" id="acht_mes" />
         <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Введите второе число" required="required" class="input-txt" name="kol_mes" id="kol_mes" />
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Введите третье число" required="required" class="input-txt" name="acht_den" id="acht_den"/>
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Введите четвертое" required="required" class="input-txt" name="kol_den" id="kol_den" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn--right" onClick="Go();">Посчитать  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: "вывода результата" - куда? Первым делом поменять `type="submit"` на `type="button"`, вторым - убрать лишние атрибуты `name`, третьим - обратить внимание на то, что хоть символы `"1"` и `"l"` и похожи, `document.forml` не существует.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов

1.Добавить в форму еще одно поле

```
<input type="text" name="output" />
```

и вставлять в него результат:

```
document.forml.kol_den.value = result;
```

2.Добавить элемент HTML

```
<div>Результат: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

и вставлять ответ в `span`

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
```

3.Выводить результат в alert

```
alert("Результат: " + result);
```

Возможно придумать что-то еще, т.к. указаные способы являются базовыми, и расширяются до бесконечности.