# Простейший калькулятор на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Требуется сделать простейший калькулятор с использованием только HTML5 и JS (без CSS).

**У меня следующий вопрос:** 
*Как создать "окно вывода результата"?
В коде два поля ввода и оператор (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`).*

```js
function calc() {
  case "+":
    console.log(A + B);
    break;

  case "-":
    console.log(A - B);
    break;

  case "*":
    console.log(A * B);
    break;

  case "/":
    console.log(A / B);
    break;
}
calc();
document.write(calc);
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" id="A">
<br>
<select id="operator">
 <option value="+">+</option>
 <option value="-">-</option> 
 <option value="*">*</option> 
 <option value="/">/</option>
</select>
<br>

<input type="number" value="0" id="B">
<br>

<button value="calc">Calc</button>
<br>
```

Comment: Это русскоязычный сайт. На будущее: не стоит дублировать вопрос на английском.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Думал так будет правильней.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В `js` существуют базовые UI операции: `alert`, `prompt` и `confirm`, которые позволяют работать с данными, полученными от пользователя.

Вам подойдет `alert`, вы можете использовать ее вместо `console.log`. Она выведет на экран окно с сообщением и приостановит выполнение скрипта, пока пользователь не нажмёт <kbd>ОК</kbd>.

Comment: kizoso, благодарю. Если я правильно понял, то "alert" выводит сообщение отдельным окном и требует нажатия кнопки "ОК" для продолжения следующего вычисления. Можно ли вывести результат непосредственно в output?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512487/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-output - нашла похожий вопрос - 3 варианта вывода, в том числе и в output

Comment: Отлично! то что доктор прописал! спасибо (-;